# Select2 box contains unwanted text

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I have recently been working on a new page where the site is using a combination of bootstrap, ASP MVC and Select2.

From the picture below, I have a select box, with it's placeholder text of 'tags' but also has this additional 'fl' text.

[image: select2 box contains 'fl' in box]

I have looked around my code and it is really perplexing as to why this is happening.

```
@partial Tags()
{    
    <div class="form-group">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("EditTags", "Tag", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <select name="Tags[]" id="tags" multiple="multiple">
                @foreach (var item in Model.AllTags)
                {
                    <option class="select2-search-choice" value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
                }
                @foreach (var item in Model.ObservableTags)
                {
                    <option class="select2-search-choice" value="@item.Id" selected="selected">@item.Name</option>
                }
            </select>

            <div class="btn-group pull-right" role="group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

In the scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function formatState(state) {
                if (!state.id) { return state.text; }
                var $state = $(
                    '<li class="select2-selection__choice" title="tag"><span class=\'glypicon glypicon-remove-circle\'/>'+state.text + '</li>'
                  );
                return $state;
            };

            $('select#tags').select2({
                placeholder: "tags",
                tags: true,
                templateResult: formatState,
                tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
            });
        });
    </script>
```

When looking at the CSS elements of this tag in Chrome, it appears that this 'fl' is being added to an 'after' element from the css.

[image: fl being added in the css]

I have looked into the CSS and JS files for Select2 and there is no reference to an 'fl' or editing the content style on this class.

I'm using Select2 4.0.0 (3.5.2 did not seem to allow me to use tags on a select element).

My setup:

Bootstrap (3.3.4)
Visual Studio 2013 pro
MVC 5

Any help here would be fantastic.

Comment: It's not "fl", it's [Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FL' (U+FB02)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fb02/index.htm). Copy the character from the [test page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fb02/browsertest.htm) and search for that.

Comment: It seems like that 'fl' is a icon from the font awesome...Check you font awesome config (path, font). You can add icons int the content rule using unicode.. ex: content:"\f002"

Answer (score 0):

ARGH, I knew the moment I posted this that I would figure it out.

I disabled the optimisation of css and javascript to make it more readable (should of done that sooner) and to my surprise it's another css file editing that :after tag for that exact component (yay for bundled layout packs). I deleted the content element and voila! problem solved.